# Непонятный load average

Tags: highload

```
top - 13:30:16 up 4 days, 20:51,  1 user,  load average: 3.12, 3.10, 3.13Tasks:  96 total,   1 running,  95 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie%Cpu0  :  0.0 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st%Cpu1  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st%Cpu2  :  0.3 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st%Cpu3  :  0.0 us,  0.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 stKiB Mem:   1884520 total,   433288 used,  1451232 free,   103648 buffersKiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.   252508 cached Mem
```

вопрос: почему же загрузка 3 (т.е. ≈75%) если все процессоры на расслабоне?

Comment: vmstat 3 10покажите?

Answer (score 1):

load average это не только нехватка процессора. LA повышают все процессы которые ждут чего-то, например ввода-вывода, или ответа от удалённого сервера.

Вообще сам по себе LA мало о чём говорит, интересно его изменение со временем.

Comment: правильно, соглашусь. чтоб прояснить, это выхлоп с wandboard'a, работающего с системой на microsd     Timing buffered disk reads:  36 MB in  3.11 seconds =  11.57 MB/secможет ли быть причина в этом? и как вообще узнать это наверняка?

Comment: Какие-то сетевые диски подключены?Покажи выхлоп `iostat 10 3`

Comment: Но вообще если проблемы нет то не надо и напрягаться.

Comment: load average показывает сумму *runable* и *uninterruptable state* (насколько помню, kill -9 их не убивает(!)) процессов.Большой процент idle и одновременно load average показывает, что есть много  uninterruptable  процессов (IMHO традиционно это нехорошо, хотя про системы с flash -- не знаю).Вывод:      ps -efl | awk '{if ($2 == "D") print $0}'должен их показать.Дальше можно использовать, например, `lsof` для более детального их просмотра.